# How to detect pts scte35 message with pts image I with ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm searching a method to detect pts of message SCTE35 with pts of an image. Do you have a suggestion?

Thank you for help

Comment: What's your research so far?

Comment: Hi Aaron, Now i just extract all image I with this command : ffmpeg -hide_banner -i File_TS.ts -vf showinfo -start_number 0 -vsync 0 -copyts fr%05d.jpg &> log.txt

Comment: I have the time signal for scte35 image but i don't know how to convert the result of ffmpeg in according to time signal scte35 message. I don't know how to interpret the pts in result of this command : ...n:   6 pts:4938839973 pts_time:54876 ...

Answer (score 1):

I use threefive to do just that.

It parses mpegts and shows the pts of the scte35 packet and the pts of the scte35 cue.

https://github.com/futzu/threefive

Answer (score 0):

So far I have successfully used [DVBInspector](http://www.digitalekabeltelevisie.nl/dvb_inspector/) for that matter.

Comment: Thank you, and with this tool you can find the lag between image I and SCTE35 message?